# SQL query performance when using nested select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

Very simple ,

This is `inner join` clause between three tables like:

```
    SELECT        dbo.Studies.DirectoryName AS StudyDirectoryName, dbo.Studies.StudyAcDate, dbo.Studies.PathRoot, dbo.Series.DirectoryName AS SeriesDirectoryName, dbo.Series.ProtocolName, 
                         dbo.Series.BodyPartExamined, dbo.Series.PatientPosition, dbo.Series.Laterality, dbo.Series.OperatorsName, dbo.Series.SeriesDate, dbo.Series.SerieTime, dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID, 
                         dbo.Series.PerformingPhysicianName, dbo.Series.InstitutionName, dbo.Series.ImageCount, dbo.Series.SerieNumber, dbo.Series.SeriesDescription, dbo.Images.SOPInstanceUID, dbo.Images.InstanceNumber, 
                         dbo.Images.ReferencedFile, dbo.Images.SOPClassUID, dbo.Images.TransferSyntax, dbo.Images.StudyInstanceUID, dbo.Images.Frames, dbo.Images.HeightPixels, dbo.Images.WidthPixels, 
                         dbo.Images.PixelSpacingX, dbo.Images.PixelSpacingY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowX, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowZ, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColX, 
                         dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColZ, dbo.Images.ImagePositionX, dbo.Images.ImagePositionY, dbo.Images.ImagePositionZ, dbo.Images.SliceThickness, 
                         dbo.Images.SliceLocation, dbo.Images.ImageType, dbo.Images.TemporalPosition, dbo.Images.NumberOfTemporalPositions
FROM  dbo.Studies
inner join  dbo.Series on dbo.Studies.StudyInstanceUID = dbo.series.StudyInstanceUID
 inner JOIN
                         dbo.Images ON dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID = dbo.Images.SeriesInstanceUID 
                         and dbo.Series.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00' and dbo.Images.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00' AND
                         Studies.StudyInstanceUID='1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.30.63366.30000017103105121748400000001' and Studies.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'
```

it will be executed in 0 second .

in the other side I have another query that use aggregate function to get `min` record like:

```
SELECT    MIN(InstanceNumber) AS MinInstanceNumber
                            FROM    dbo.Images
                            WHERE   StudyInstanceUID='1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.30.63366.30000017103105121748400000001' 
                            and StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'  
                            GROUP BY SeriesInstanceUID
```

this will be executed in zero second also.

but when I combine these two queries as:

```
SELECT        dbo.Studies.DirectoryName AS StudyDirectoryName, dbo.Studies.StudyAcDate, dbo.Studies.PathRoot, dbo.Series.DirectoryName AS SeriesDirectoryName, dbo.Series.ProtocolName, 
                             dbo.Series.BodyPartExamined, dbo.Series.PatientPosition, dbo.Series.Laterality, dbo.Series.OperatorsName, dbo.Series.SeriesDate, dbo.Series.SerieTime, dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID, 
                             dbo.Series.PerformingPhysicianName, dbo.Series.InstitutionName, dbo.Series.ImageCount, dbo.Series.SerieNumber, dbo.Series.SeriesDescription, dbo.Images.SOPInstanceUID, dbo.Images.InstanceNumber, 
                             dbo.Images.ReferencedFile, dbo.Images.SOPClassUID, dbo.Images.TransferSyntax, dbo.Images.StudyInstanceUID, dbo.Images.Frames, dbo.Images.HeightPixels, dbo.Images.WidthPixels, 
                             dbo.Images.PixelSpacingX, dbo.Images.PixelSpacingY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowX, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowZ, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColX, 
                             dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColZ, dbo.Images.ImagePositionX, dbo.Images.ImagePositionY, dbo.Images.ImagePositionZ, dbo.Images.SliceThickness, 
                             dbo.Images.SliceLocation, dbo.Images.ImageType, dbo.Images.TemporalPosition, dbo.Images.NumberOfTemporalPositions
    FROM  dbo.Studies
    inner join  dbo.Series on dbo.Studies.StudyInstanceUID = dbo.series.StudyInstanceUID
     inner JOIN
                             dbo.Images ON dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID = dbo.Images.SeriesInstanceUID 
                             and dbo.Series.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00' and dbo.Images.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00' AND
                             Studies.StudyInstanceUID='1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.30.63366.30000017103105121748400000001' and Studies.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'
                             and dbo.Images.InstanceNumber IN
                                 (SELECT    MIN(InstanceNumber) AS MinInstanceNumber
                                    FROM    dbo.Images
                                    WHERE   StudyInstanceUID='1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.30.63366.30000017103105121748400000001' 
                                    and StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'  
                                    GROUP BY SeriesInstanceUID)
```

it will take 42 seconds to run

so is there better way to implement this scenario ? and why it take so long to be run?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

The subquery will find 48 records each record have number 1 , it take long to run but when I changed the subquery like:

```
    SELECT        dbo.Studies.DirectoryName AS StudyDirectoryName, dbo.Studies.StudyAcDate, dbo.Studies.PathRoot, dbo.Series.DirectoryName AS SeriesDirectoryName, dbo.Series.ProtocolName, 
                         dbo.Series.BodyPartExamined, dbo.Series.PatientPosition, dbo.Series.Laterality, dbo.Series.OperatorsName, dbo.Series.SeriesDate, dbo.Series.SerieTime, dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID, 
                         dbo.Series.PerformingPhysicianName, dbo.Series.InstitutionName, dbo.Series.ImageCount, dbo.Series.SerieNumber, dbo.Series.SeriesDescription, dbo.Images.SOPInstanceUID, dbo.Images.InstanceNumber, 
                         dbo.Images.ReferencedFile, dbo.Images.SOPClassUID, dbo.Images.TransferSyntax, dbo.Images.StudyInstanceUID, dbo.Images.Frames, dbo.Images.HeightPixels, dbo.Images.WidthPixels, 
                         dbo.Images.PixelSpacingX, dbo.Images.PixelSpacingY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowX, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowZ, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColX, 
                         dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColZ, dbo.Images.ImagePositionX, dbo.Images.ImagePositionY, dbo.Images.ImagePositionZ, dbo.Images.SliceThickness, 
                         dbo.Images.SliceLocation, dbo.Images.ImageType, dbo.Images.TemporalPosition, dbo.Images.NumberOfTemporalPositions
FROM  dbo.Studies
inner join  dbo.Series on dbo.Studies.StudyInstanceUID = dbo.series.StudyInstanceUID
 inner JOIN
                         dbo.Images ON dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID = dbo.Images.SeriesInstanceUID 
                         and dbo.Series.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00' and dbo.Images.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00' AND
                         Studies.StudyInstanceUID='1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.30.63366.30000017103105121748400000001' and Studies.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'
                         and dbo.Images.InstanceNumber IN (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

it be executed immediately.

Why really this happened when I use `select` subquery , is it running per records ?

Comment: Move the subquery to the `from` clause.  The database will optimize it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have to split it and execute subquery in a temp table like:

```
    DECLARE @MinTbl TABLE( MinInstanceNumber int)
 Insert into @MinTbl(MinInstanceNumber) SELECT  MIN(InstanceNumber) AS MinInstanceNumber
                                FROM    dbo.Images
                                WHERE   StudyInstanceUID=@uid and StudyAcDate=@daterange
                                GROUP BY SeriesInstanceUID
```

and then run the main query over `@MinTbl` like:

```
    SELECT dbo.Studies.DirectoryName AS StudyDirectoryName, dbo.Studies.StudyAcDate, dbo.Studies.PathRoot, dbo.Series.DirectoryName AS SeriesDirectoryName, dbo.Series.ProtocolName, 
                         dbo.Series.BodyPartExamined, dbo.Series.PatientPosition, dbo.Series.Laterality, dbo.Series.OperatorsName, dbo.Series.SeriesDate, dbo.Series.SerieTime, dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID, 
                         dbo.Series.PerformingPhysicianName, dbo.Series.InstitutionName, dbo.Series.ImageCount, dbo.Series.SerieNumber, dbo.Series.SeriesDescription, dbo.Images.SOPInstanceUID, dbo.Images.InstanceNumber, 
                         dbo.Images.ReferencedFile, dbo.Images.SOPClassUID, dbo.Images.TransferSyntax, dbo.Images.StudyInstanceUID, dbo.Images.Frames, dbo.Images.HeightPixels, dbo.Images.WidthPixels, 
                         dbo.Images.PixelSpacingX, dbo.Images.PixelSpacingY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowX, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowZ, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColX, 
                         dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColZ, dbo.Images.ImagePositionX, dbo.Images.ImagePositionY, dbo.Images.ImagePositionZ, dbo.Images.SliceThickness, 
                         dbo.Images.SliceLocation, dbo.Images.ImageType, dbo.Images.TemporalPosition, dbo.Images.NumberOfTemporalPositions
  FROM  dbo.Studies inner join  dbo.Series on dbo.Studies.StudyInstanceUID = dbo.series.StudyInstanceUID inner JOIN 
                     dbo.Images ON dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID = dbo.Images.SeriesInstanceUID 
                     and dbo.Series.StudyAcDate=@daterange  and dbo.Images.StudyAcDate=@daterange 
                     and dbo.Studies.StudyInstanceUID=@uid and dbo.Studies.StudyAcDate=@daterange 
                     and Images.InstanceNumber in (select MinInstanceNumber from @MinTbl)
```

this is very efficient, these two queries will run very fast.

I think when we use select with `in` , the subquery will run per record I don't know why.

It will be main answer until other best answer posted.

thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Use CTE syntax :

```
with temp as (
  SELECT MIN(InstanceNumber) AS MinInstanceNumber
  FROM   dbo.Images
  WHERE  StudyInstanceUID='1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.30.63366.30000017103105121748400000001' 
    AND  StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'  
  GROUP BY SeriesInstanceUID
)
SELECT
    dbo.Studies.DirectoryName AS StudyDirectoryName,
    dbo.Studies.StudyAcDate,
    dbo.Studies.PathRoot,
    dbo.Series.DirectoryName AS SeriesDirectoryName,
    dbo.Series.ProtocolName,
    dbo.Series.BodyPartExamined,
    dbo.Series.PatientPosition,
    dbo.Series.Laterality,
    dbo.Series.OperatorsName,
    dbo.Series.SeriesDate,
    dbo.Series.SerieTime, 
    dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID,
    dbo.Series.PerformingPhysicianName,
    dbo.Series.InstitutionName,
    dbo.Series.ImageCount,
    dbo.Series.SerieNumber,
    dbo.Series.SeriesDescription,
    dbo.Images.SOPInstanceUID,
    dbo.Images.InstanceNumber, 
    dbo.Images.ReferencedFile,
    dbo.Images.SOPClassUID,
    dbo.Images.TransferSyntax,
    dbo.Images.StudyInstanceUID,
    dbo.Images.Frames,
    dbo.Images.HeightPixels,
    dbo.Images.WidthPixels,
    dbo.Images.PixelSpacingX,
    dbo.Images.PixelSpacingY,
    dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowX,
    dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowY,
    dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowZ,
    dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColX,
    dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColY,
    dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColZ,
    dbo.Images.ImagePositionX,
    dbo.Images.ImagePositionY,
    dbo.Images.ImagePositionZ,
    dbo.Images.SliceThickness,
    dbo.Images.SliceLocation,
    dbo.Images.ImageType, 
    dbo.Images.TemporalPosition,
    dbo.Images.NumberOfTemporalPositions
FROM
    dbo.Studies
    inner join  dbo.Series on
        dbo.Studies.StudyInstanceUID = dbo.series.StudyInstanceUID
    inner JOIN  dbo.Images ON
        dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID = dbo.Images.SeriesInstanceUID 
        and dbo.Series.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'
        and dbo.Images.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'
        AND Studies.StudyInstanceUID='1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.30.63366.30000017103105121748400000001'
        and Studies.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'
        and dbo.Images.InstanceNumber IN (select MinInstanceNumber from temp)
```

Comment: Thanks but your query is not correct, and I am really looking the main reason of that...

Comment: I have remove and extra comma before the second `SELECT`, can you retry ?

Comment: It's ok I have change the end

Comment: Thank you, I can't accept it as an answer,  because it is not efficient and does not have any performance than my query , it will take 42 seconds also !!!, but really thank you for your attention.

Comment: It seem to be true, but I really don't know why it take long time also.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding why SQL performs worse in these cases can be quite complex.  Be careful on which table columns you perform JOINs.  The query will run faster if both columns are indexed.  This is particularly true when either table in a JOIN has a large number of rows.  Also, make sure that the *data types and lengths are exactly the same* for the columns participating in the JOIN.

In SQL Server Management Studio, choose the Display Estimated Query Plan option from the Query menu when executing the query to see if it recommends an new index that may help this query run faster.  If you choose to implement the recommendation, be mindful of any existing indexes that may be affected by this new one.  While implementing an index can help query performance, generally indexes also negatively affect INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE performance.

This is just one quick fix for the query in question.  A more comprehensive approach analyzing index usage, fragmentation, and other database settings can result in a healthier system overall.  A regular maintenance plan is also recommended.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right, our DB is tuned because of partitioning and indexing, and I perform `inner join` over tables keys , It is important how query is apart from records number.

Answer (score 0):

If the inner query is the select statement it is executed for every row.
By placing the inner query in the FROM statement the query is executed only once.

Here is my humble attempt to rewrite the query:

```
    SELECT       
    dbo.Studies.DirectoryName AS StudyDirectoryName, dbo.Studies.StudyAcDate, dbo.Studies.PathRoot, dbo.Series.DirectoryName AS SeriesDirectoryName, dbo.Series.ProtocolName, 
    dbo.Series.BodyPartExamined, dbo.Series.PatientPosition, dbo.Series.Laterality, dbo.Series.OperatorsName, dbo.Series.SeriesDate, dbo.Series.SerieTime, dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID, 
    dbo.Series.PerformingPhysicianName, dbo.Series.InstitutionName, dbo.Series.ImageCount, dbo.Series.SerieNumber, dbo.Series.SeriesDescription, dbo.Images.SOPInstanceUID, dbo.Images.InstanceNumber, 
    dbo.Images.ReferencedFile, dbo.Images.SOPClassUID, dbo.Images.TransferSyntax, dbo.Images.StudyInstanceUID, dbo.Images.Frames, dbo.Images.HeightPixels, dbo.Images.WidthPixels, 
    dbo.Images.PixelSpacingX, dbo.Images.PixelSpacingY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowX, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationRowZ, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColX, 
    dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColY, dbo.Images.ImageOrientationColZ, dbo.Images.ImagePositionX, dbo.Images.ImagePositionY, dbo.Images.ImagePositionZ, dbo.Images.SliceThickness, 
    dbo.Images.SliceLocation, dbo.Images.ImageType, dbo.Images.TemporalPosition, dbo.Images.NumberOfTemporalPositions
FROM 
    dbo.Studies
    inner join  dbo.Series on dbo.Studies.StudyInstanceUID = dbo.series.StudyInstanceUID
    inner JOIN dbo.Images ON
        dbo.Series.SeriesInstanceUID = dbo.Images.SeriesInstanceUID 
    inner join          
        (SELECT MIN(Images.InstanceNumber) AS MinInstanceNumber,Images.StudyInstanceUID  FROM dbo.Images
        where   Images.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00' 
        GROUP BY Images.SeriesInstanceUID,Images.StudyInstanceUID) AS X 
        ON X.StudyInstanceUID = Studies.StudyInstanceUID and dbo.Images.InstanceNumber = x.MinInstanceNumber
WHERE
    dbo.Series.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00' 
    and dbo.Images.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00' 
    AND Studies.StudyInstanceUID='1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.30.63366.30000017103105121748400000001' 
    and Studies.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'
```

Comment: Thanks, but `X.StudyInstanceUID` does not exist, because it is not selected in subquery.

Comment: Yes, I have edited your query because of some syntax errors, but you know it will give me lot of records which are not my expect...

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question but I would strongly recommend you start using aliases in your queries. Also adding some formatting can turn this wall of text query which is nearly impossible to decipher into something that is very easy to see what is going on. Here is your query with aliases and some formatting. I have no idea why you have that long list of 1s in the IN at the end of this but whatever.

```
SELECT st.DirectoryName AS StudyDirectoryName
    , st.StudyAcDate
    , st.PathRoot
    , se.DirectoryName AS SeriesDirectoryName
    , se.ProtocolName
    , se.BodyPartExamined
    , se.PatientPosition
    , se.Laterality
    , se.OperatorsName
    , se.SeriesDate
    , se.SerieTime
    , se.SeriesInstanceUID
    , se.PerformingPhysicianName
    , se.InstitutionName
    , se.ImageCount
    , se.SerieNumber
    , se.SeriesDescription
    , i.SOPInstanceUID
    , i.InstanceNumber
    , i.ReferencedFile
    , i.SOPClassUID
    , i.TransferSyntax
    , i.StudyInstanceUID
    , i.Frames
    , i.HeightPixels
    , i.WidthPixels
    , i.PixelSpacingX
    , i.PixelSpacingY
    , i.ImageOrientationRowX
    , i.ImageOrientationRowY
    , i.ImageOrientationRowZ
    , i.ImageOrientationColX
    , i.ImageOrientationColY
    , i.ImageOrientationColZ
    , i.ImagePositionX
    , i.ImagePositionY
    , i.ImagePositionZ
    , i.SliceThickness
    , i.SliceLocation
    , i.ImageType
    , i.TemporalPosition
    , i.NumberOfTemporalPositions
FROM dbo.Studies st
inner join dbo.Series se on st.StudyInstanceUID = se.StudyInstanceUID
inner JOIN dbo.Images i ON se.SeriesInstanceUID = i.SeriesInstanceUID 
                        and se.StudyAcDate = '2017-10-31 08:42:00' 
                        and i.StudyAcDate = '2017-10-31 08:42:00' 
                        AND Studies.StudyInstanceUID = '1.3.12.2.1107.5.2.30.63366.30000017103105121748400000001' 
                        and Studies.StudyAcDate='2017-10-31 08:42:00'
                        and i.InstanceNumber IN (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```